# 9 div rounded dispay with on click evant

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need 9 rounded div grid, like in photo. And when i click one div, it change color and change main div content, and when i click another first small div go back to normal color and second small clicked div change color and div content and etc. And if you click oustside of divv all divs came back to normal. Any suggestion ?

You could see what i made here (sorry dont know how to put evrything in jsquerty so theris is drive file with css and index: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7vEkZyPAXMeWRrV0daYXhNXzQ/view?usp=sharing

**Div grids**:   [image: how it looks[1]] 
**First click:** [image: first click change color]
**second click:** [image: second click fist go back to nromal] **if you click anywhere except divs all goes back to start:** [image]

Comment: Can't see your drive file - needs permission. Maybe post code directly on this page that is pertinent.

Comment: or share a fiddle with us..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is fairly simple event based toggling of classes...study some tutorials or provide code attempts that aren't working

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for bad link, now i fix the link so anybody culd see the content.

Comment: I will not download anything on the internet from a stranger, Please read @Paulie_D post, and paste your code here, and plus a http://jsfiddle.net/ will be nice.

Comment: I have somthing like this http://jsfiddle.net/Gn9g4/1/, but dont know how to make it moving. I try use this script for change color of the inner divs: <script>
$('#ic_giving').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img/ic_giving.png')
            ? 'img/ic_giving_yellow.png'
            : 'img/ic_giving.png';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});</script>

Comment: And this code for change it inside div:     <script type="text/javascript">
   function toggle_visibility(type1) {
       var e = document.getElementById(type1);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
   }
</script>
But its not working with many divs, and it dont back at start by clicking anywhere